# SingleCompile plugin Installation in vim

Tags: vim, gvim, vim-plugins

I'm using debian wheezy. I've downloaded [**SingleCompile**](http://vim.sourceforge.net/scripts/script.php?script_id=3115) plugin and I installed in vim 7.4.
As there's no directory like `~/.vim` I created one using `mkdir ~/.vim` 
and move the extracted  plugins to `~/.vim/autoloads`. I've edited the `vimrc` too:

```
filetype plugin on
```

and also added,

```
nmap <F9> :SCCompile<cr>
nmap <F10> :SCCompileRun<cr>
```

as instructed without any trailing space in vimrc.

Now the problem I got is when I try to compile a c program:

```
E492: Not an editor command:SCCompile
```

plz help me with this.

Answer (score 1):

The command is not available because you didn't follow the installation instruction carefully.

*All* the directories/files in the archive must go into your `~/.vim` directory:

```
SingleCompile-2.11.0/            |   ~/.vim/
                     autoload/   |          autoload/
                     doc/        >          doc/
                     plugin/     |          plugin/
```

Once your setup is done, the command and the mapping will work normally (barring other still unknown issues).